# How can I retrieve all values for a column key in a multidimensional ArrayTable?

Tags: java, guava

I'm trying to retrieve all matrix values from a multidimensional array table, using Google's Guava tables package. Right now, I can get all elements for a specific column key as follows:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.common.collect.ArrayTable;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.collect.Table;

public class createMatrixTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Setup table just like a matrix in R
        List<String> universityRowTable = Lists.newArrayList("Mumbai", "Harvard");
        List<String> courseColumnTables = Lists.newArrayList("Chemical", "IT", "Electrical");
        Table<String, String, Integer> universityCourseSeatTable = ArrayTable.create(universityRowTable, courseColumnTables);

        // Populate the values of the table directly
        universityCourseSeatTable.put("Mumbai", "Chemical", 120);
        universityCourseSeatTable.put("Mumbai", "IT", 60);
        universityCourseSeatTable.put("Harvard", "Electrical", 60);
        universityCourseSeatTable.put("Harvard", "IT", 120);

        // Get all of the elements of a specific column 
        Map<String, Integer> courseSeatMap = universityCourseSeatTable.column("IT");

        // Print out those elements
        System.out.println(courseSeatMap);

    }

}
```

Which returns the following in the console:

```
{Mumbai=60, Harvard=120}
```

How can I assign just the values (60 and 120) to an array variable without the row keys?

```
List<Integer> courseSeatValuesIT = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Such that if I were to print the list, it would return the following:

```
// Print out the variable with just values
System.out.println(courseSeatValuesIT);

[60,120]
```

Thanks to any Java rock stars who take the time to help out a new guy!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want only values from specified column, just use `.values()` on returned map:

```
Collection<Integer> courseSeatValuesIT = courseSeatMap.values();
System.out.println(courseSeatValuesIT);
```

If you need list, copy it to new one:

```
List<Integer> courseSeatValuesIT = new ArrayList<>(courseSeatMap.values());
```

Note that you're using `ArrayTable` here, which is fixed-size and requires [*allowed row and column keys must be supplied when the table is created*](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayTable.html). If you ever want to add new row / column (ex. `"Oxford"` -> `"Law"` -> value), you should use [`HashBasedTable`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html) in first place.

Comment: Great answer - it works!! One more thing, how could you assign a list of integers to the same column? For example, instead of universityCourseSeatTable.put("Mumbai", "IT", 60) and universityCourseSeatTable.put("Harvard", "IT", 120), how could I just do universityCourseSeatTable.put("IT") = [60, 120]?

Comment: Not really, especially in case of `HashBasedTable` order is not deterministic, so there's really no way to match 60 to Mumbai and 120 to Harvard in your example. You could however fetch `universityCourseSeatTable.column("IT")` map and experiment with that.